# How to refactor this code from two methods down to one method

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I have the following two methods that are very similar:

```
            def space_before_element?(start_element)
                element = start_element.previous_element
                until element.nil? ||
                (element.name == start_element.name || "r" && !element.text.empty?)
                  element = element.previous_element
                end
                character = element
                           .text
                           .split(/(\W)/)
                           .compact
                           .reject(&:empty?)
                           .last
                           .last_character \
                           unless element.nil? 

                element.nil? || 
                (character.punctuation? && !character.hyphen? && !character.apostrophe?) || 
                character.spaces? 
              end


            def space_after_element?(start_element)
                element = start_element.next_element
                until element.nil? ||
                (element.name == start_element.name || "r" && !element.text.empty?)
                  element = element.next_element
                end
                character = element
                           .text
                           .split(/(\W)/)
                           .compact
                           .reject(&:empty?)
                           .last
                           .first_character \
                           unless element.nil? 

                element.nil? || 
                (character.punctuation? && !character.hyphen? && !character.apostrophe?) || 
                character.spaces? 
              end
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make the necessary changes that would allow me to reduce this down to one method.

Still getting my Ruby skills going.

Any help appreciated.
Ruby 2.2.3

Comment: What's with all the `**`'s? You should only include valid Ruby code. (I expect that's the reason for the downvote.) Also, some readers, myself included, are annoyed when we have to scroll horizontally to read code. How about breaking lines so that's not needed?

Comment: I was trying to bold the items in the methods that were different using the tools provided here to help make it easier to see the differences. I will follow your advice and break the up so its not needed. Apologies.

Comment: You can keep common set of lines in a one method, The logic that varies can be wrapped as blocks/procs, can be passed as argument on invoking method

Comment: In which class are those methods defined?

Comment: These methods are defined in the Section class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I counted three differences. So, these differences should be explicitly declared:

```
METHODS = {
  prev: [:previous_element, %i|last last_character|],
  next: [:next_element, %i|first first_character|]
}.freeze
```

Now we just pass a parameter to the method:

```
def space_around_element?(start_element, prev_or_next = :prev)
    element = start_element.public_send(METHODS[prev_or_next].first)
    # same code
    character = element
               .text
               .split(/(\W)/)
               .reject(&:empty?)
               .public_send(METHODS[prev_or_next].last.first)
               .public_send(METHODS[prev_or_next].last.last) \
      unless element.nil? 
    # same code
  end
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help with this I'm learning a lot from this answer.